# Converting tuples of (x,y) coordinates to a tuple of x and a tuple of y coordinates

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, tuples

What's a cleaner, less repeating way to pass in the coordinates here?:

```
plt.plot((point_A[0], point_B[0], point_C[0], point_D[0], point_E[0], point_F[0]), (point_A[1], point_B[1], point_C[1], point_D[1], point_E[1], point_F[1]))
```

They have values like `point_A = (2,3)`

I haven't written python in a while and I'd like to be idiomatic and writing clear/obvious code, without repeating.

Comment: share the docs of the exact API that you are using (`plot`)

Comment: Can you save all the points to a list? `points = [point_A, point_B, point_C, point_D, point_E, point_F]`?

Comment: @balderman https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just `zip`:

```
plt.plot(*zip(point_A, point_B, point_C))
```

If your points are already in a list, you can use

```
# points = [point_A, point_B, ...]
plt.plot(*zip(*points))
```

Answer (score 1):

`zip` is your friend here.

```py
list_of_tuples = [point_A, point_B, point_C, point_D, point_E, point_F]
list_of_coords = list(zip(*list_of_tuples))
```